# Python not listening on any port that I specify

Tags: python, sockets, server, port

I'm performing a [simple Python socket tutorial.](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html) I initialize the socket using

```
import socket
import sys
# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server = socket.gethostname()
port = 8080
server_address = (server,port)
sock.listen(1)
```

But when I check the ports that my Ubuntu machine is listening on with `netstat -ntulp` I get

```
...
tcp    0   0 0.0.0.0:49064     0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN   12505/python 
...
```

It's listening on port `49604` instead of port `8080`! Note that I have tried this with many different ports everything from `4242` to `47806`; random ports that aren't being used.

Why is my program not listening on the port that I've defined?

Comment: Did you forget to bind your socket?

Comment: You're not doing anything that would change the port number of your socket, so it uses the default.

Comment: I forgot to bind my socket. Thank you both!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual bind part is only present in your comments, but not your code. Call [`bind`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind):

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 8080
sock.bind(('', port)) # actually bind
sock.listen(1)
```

Note that I changed the address. If you want to be reachable from everywhere, pass in an empty string like here. If you only want to be reachable from localhost, pass in `'localhost'` (or `::1` for IPv6 sockets which you really should be using, by the way).

Passing the machine name is wrong for many reasons; since machine name is interpreted as a DNS name. A number of errors or problems can occur:

- In the best case, there is an entry in `/etc/hosts` which matches the one for `localhost`. Canonically, for IPv4 this entry is 127.0.0.1.
- Slightly worse is when your code is running on a debian-like system, where the hostname resolves to 127.0.**1**.1. Now your service is reachable under that IP, but not 127.0.0.1.
- If the machine name is not present in `/etc/hosts` (this happens regularly in case of incomplete changes, and some systems set it up that way, for example chrooted onces), you will trigger a DNS resolution, hopefully in the local network. In the best case, you get a result, you're now available to everyone in the local network under the computer's network IP address (any randomly selected if you have multiple). Your service will **not** be available for applications contacting localhost.
- Even worse, the name resolution may fail for whatever reason.
- Even worse, the name resolution may succeed, but not actually return your machine's IP address, or return an unrouted address of your machine. This will either fail outright or you'll listen on an address nobody uses anymore, so your service will be essentially unreachable.
- Even worse, your query may escape to the Internet, which may allow somebody to coerce your service to be open to the world.

In the best case binding to your hostname will fail outright. In the worst case, it may work for some applications by sheer luck, but fail on a lot of other machines. Bind to `'localhost'`, `''`, or let the user configure the IP; depending on whether you want your service to be only available to the local machine, everyone, or a user-configured subset.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and the background information!

Comment: too rare answer/people like this nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

As SergeyA and kindall mentioned, you forgot to bind your socket. Add

```
sock.bind(server_address)
```

to the bottom of your program to bind your socket to a specific port.